# Global state to check session duration in Flink ProcessWindowFunction

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to Fink,and want to calculate keyed total session duration for a `EventFormDTO` stream:

```
    {"id":1,"projectId":1,"eventTypeId":1,"sessionId":"session_1","status":"IN_QUEUQ","comment":"","del":false,"millSecs":1}
{"id":1,"projectId":1,"eventTypeId":1,"sessionId":"session_2","status":"IN_QUEUQ","comment":"","del":false,"millSecs":5}
{"id":1,"projectId":1,"eventTypeId":1,"sessionId":"session_1","status":"ON_GOING","comment":"","del":false,"millSecs":10}
{"id":1,"projectId":1,"eventTypeId":1,"sessionId":"session_2","status":"ON_GOING","comment":"","del":false,"millSecs":18}
```

`IN_QUEUE` means the begin of session while `ON_GOING` is the end of session. The expected output should be the total duration per keyed, when an event arrives. Therefore, a sample output for the above data is

```
ts        duration
timestamp_1  0
timestamp_2  4   // session_1: 5-1
timestamp_3  14  //(10-1)+ (10-5)  both session_1 and session_2 are active, and then session_1 end
timestamp_4  13  //18-5   the session_1 has already end.
```

In my implementation, I used a `ProcessWindowFun` and a global `MapState` to track <session_id, start_time>. My sample code is like:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    final DataStream<EventFormDTO> stream = ...;
    stream.keyBy(new KeySelector<EventFormDTO, String>() {
        @Override
        public String getKey(EventFormDTO eventFormDTO) throws Exception {
            return eventFormDTO.getProjectId()+"-"+eventFormDTO.getEventTypeId();
        }
    }).window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(30))).process(new EventProcessWindowFun()).print();
    try {
        log.info("Start application.");
        env.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EventFormDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5034868557373901846L;
    Long  id;
    Integer projectId;
    Integer eventTypeId;
    String sessionId;
    String status;
    String comment;
    Boolean del;
    Long millSecs;
}

@Slf4j
public class EventProcessWindowFun extends ProcessWindowFunction<EventFormDTO, Tuple2<Long, Long>, String, TimeWindow> {
    //session_id --> startTime.

    final static MapStateDescriptor<String, Long> descriptor =
            new MapStateDescriptor<>(
                    "record", // the state name
                    BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO, BasicTypeInfo.LONG_TYPE_INFO
            );

    @Override
    public void process(String s, Context context, Iterable<EventFormDTO> iterable, Collector<Tuple2<Long, Long>> collector) throws Exception {
        MapState<String, Long > keyedMeasure = context.globalState().getMapState(descriptor);
        log.info("obtain reference to Map success.. ");
        for(EventFormDTO event: iterable){
            String sessionId = event.getSessionId();
            Long timeStamp = event.getMillSecs();
            String status = event.getStatus();
            Long duration = 0L;
            if(keyedMeasure.contains(sessionId)){
                duration += timeStamp - keyedMeasure.get(sessionId);
                keyedMeasure.remove(sessionId);
            }else{
                keyedMeasure.put(sessionId, timeStamp);
            }

            collector.collect(new Tuple2(context.window().getEnd(), duration));
        }
    }

}
```

However, during the debug, I can not get what I wanted.

Each time the `EventProcessWindowFun` is called, the globalstate `keyedMeasure` is newly object and does not have any data that were calculated in previous window.

Therefore, I want to ask

1. How to obtain globalState in the ProcessWindowFunction?
2. Is ProcessWindowFunction sutiable for my case? is there other better solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keyedMeasure` will never contain keys that come from the `status`. I believe you meant to write

```java
if (keyedMeasure.contains(sessionId)) {
    duration += timeStamp - keyedMeasure.get(sessionId);
    keyedMeasure.remove(sessionId);
} else {
    keyedMeasure.put(sessionId, timeStamp)
}
```

It seems like the logic will become simpler if you include the `sessionId` as part of the key. Then you can use `ValueState` rather than `MapState`.

Also, you might want to do this with a `RichFlatMapFunction` or a `KeyedProcessFunction` instead of using windows. By using windows you are imposing a sort of mini-batching on something that can be done more naturally with continuous stream processing.